# Evaluating: $ \int\sqrt{\tanh(\ln(\sqrt{x}))} dx$ ; $ \int \ln\left(\sqrt{\tanh(\ln(\sqrt{x}))}\right) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, hyperbolic-functions

I don't have much experience with hyperbolic trig functions... So I don't know how to start solving this. How do I evaluate the following integrals? Any advice, hint or well-thought solution will be appreciated.

$$I_1= \int\sqrt{\tanh(\ln(\sqrt{x}))} dx$$
$$I_2= \int \ln\left(\sqrt{\tanh(\ln(\sqrt{x}))}\right) dx$$

---

Background: I made these up while solving similar problems from the internet.. I checked WA for the closed form, but I don't know how to arrive at them...

Comment: where did you got this?

Comment: Hint: $\tanh x=\sinh x/\cosh x$, and express $\sinh x$ and $\cosh x$ in terms of $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$.

Comment: @kennytm Alright, I'll try that.

Comment: A downvote; how wonderful.

Comment: @downvoter please explain your exasperation with this question.

Comment: what did you try, maybe nothing?

Comment: @ADG Of course I didn't try anything sir, because I had no idea where to start. I even mentioned it in the original post that I don't have much experience with hyperbolic trig func, hence I don't know how to start solving it.  I posted this question, and have been scourging the internet for identities regarding the hypertrigfunc as a learning experience. Not every question can have some effort put in...It makes no sense!

Comment: I have mentioned it my friend; the first sentence of my post concerns this. @ADG

Comment: btw did you noticed my answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\sqrt{\tanh(\ln(\sqrt{x}))}=\sqrt{\frac{e^{2\ln(\sqrt x)}-1}{e^{2\ln(\sqrt x)}+1}}=\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x+1}}$$
Now:
$$I_1=\int\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x+1}}dx\\\stackrel{x=\cosh 2t}=4\int\sinh^2tdt=\sinh(2t)-2t+c\\=\sqrt{x^2-1}-\cosh^{-1}x+c$$

---

$$I_2\stackrel{x=\cosh 2t}=4\int\sinh(t)\ln(\tanh (t))dt\\=4\cosh t\ln(\tanh t)-4\int {\rm csch} t
\\=4\cosh t\ln(\tanh t)-4\ln|{\rm csch} t-\coth t|+c\\= \sqrt2 \sqrt{x+1}  \ln\frac{x-1}{x+1}-4 \ln\left(-\tanh\left(\frac 14 \cosh^{-1}(x)\right)\right)+c$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Recall the definition of [hyperbolic tangent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Standard_algebraic_expressions).

$$ \tanh x = \frac{\sinh x}{\cosh x} = \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{e^x + e^{-x}} = \frac{e^{2x} - 1}{e^{2x} + 1} $$

Substitute this directly into the integrand $\sqrt{\tanh (\ln \sqrt x)}$ to simplify.